# If I add a child view controller, and use it to present another view controller, the whole root view is replaced?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uikit

On iOS 5, if I add a child view controller `addChildViewController` and add its view, say, at (0, 100) and covers up the whole bottom screen, and then in this new child view controller, present another view controller using `presentViewController` with a flipping animation, I thought only the child view will flip and present a new view, but it turns out the whole view (the whole screen except the status bar) is flipped?

I thought they work in a "self-contained manner"?  That is, if a child view controller presents another view controller, the child view controller's view is replaced, not the root view?

(so if the presented view controller's view has a yellow background, now the whole screen except the status bar has the color yellow, instead of just the child view controller's view which starts at (0,100) and covers up the bottom screen)

Answer (score 6):

Set `childViewController.definesPresentationContext = YES`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to only flip the child view controller, you need to add the views of the controllers to the root view controller's view hierarchy (phew! say that 2x as fast!) and then use a `UIView` animation to animate them.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:controllerB.view
                    toView:controllerC.view
                  duration:0.33
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    // whatever completion code you need
                }];
```

Comment: I think this will work, just that I hoped originally to do everything in a "self contained" manner by various types of view controllers

Comment: @JeremyL Apple allowed for child view controllers to, among many things, solve the problem of: I have multiple controllers but I don't want them to create these ladders of delegate calls just to do something as simple as push a new view controller on the stack or, in your case, present a modal view controller.  `UIViewController` containment was not designed to be a self contained 'let me do some transitions'.